# My game seems to be incompatible with recording software. What could be causing this?

Tags: c++, opengl, glfw, screen-recording

I've just finished a little Game-Dev project for university and I need to record a video to accompany my submission (just in case they can't get my source to work). Basically my game doesn't work at all when FRAPS or Bandicam attempts to attach to it, I get a black screen and a stream of GL INVALID OPERATION messages from my error reporting code. Dxtory can't seem to hook into it correctly at all, it doesn't display it's FPS counter or anything. My game logic appears to be running correctly from the debug traces, it just seems like all the gl library calls break.

I don't know a huge amount about how these programs operate so I don't really know what I could be doing to cause this. I've heard they read from the OpenGL frame buffers so maybe I'm doing something wrong there? I'm letting GLFW and GLEW do all the low level initialization, but I have successfully recorded projects with the same setup and recording software.

Essentially, has anyone ever run into something like this before or do you know anything about how these programs work that could give a clue as to the cause of the issue?

Comment: most screen capturing apps work by wedging themselves between your app and its DLL's, then they just copy the frames as they get sent to the OS to be displayed. I don't have experience with GLFW and GLEW but if you are not using the normal OpenGL frame buffer, the capturing apps may not be looking at the right thing.

Comment: Please can you try with OBS/Open Broadcaster software? It requires a bit of learning but it can usually tell you which version (32/64bit) to use and what applications/games it can detect. There is a good how to somewhere online on using OBS as well. It can do both Desktop and Game mode.

Comment: You may want to go the hardware route with this one. Even if you can get FRAPs or the like working, those things can eat up some resources and drop your framerate considerably.

Comment: Cheers Vangel. OBS seems to work perfectly. I had to recompile my game as a non-console application but afterwards it worked fine. I also got a very low ammount of frame drop compared to what I'd expect from recorders. If you want to officially answer I'll accept it as correct.

Comment: Try double buffering. FRAPS (for instance) doesn't recognize the buffers if its not double buffered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question was answered and resolved by Vangel.

Would like to add this answer because no one else will, nor has for 2 months, but this is appearing at the top as "Unanswered" and in need of help.

Would vote to close if I could.

> Please can you try with OBS/Open Broadcaster software? It requires a
> bit of learning but it can usually tell you which version (32/64bit)
> to use and what applications/games it can detect. There is a good how
> to somewhere online on using OBS as well. It can do both Desktop and
> Game mode.
>
> – Vangel Apr 30 at 16:29

Replied by Asker,

> Cheers Vangel. OBS seems to work perfectly. I had to recompile my game
> as a non-console application but afterwards it worked fine. I also got
> a very low ammount of frame drop compared to what I'd expect from
> recorders. If you want to officially answer I'll accept it as correct.
>
> – Lewis Wakeford Apr 30 at 18:23